# How can I bring down the interface in the netplan configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, netplan

I have an Ubuntu server 18.04 and simple netplan configuration (see below):

```
---
network:
  ethernets:
    ens1:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
      - "192.168.99.1/24"
    ens2:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
      - "172.20.0.82/23"
      gateway4: "172.20.0.1"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - "172.20.0.62"
  renderer: "networkd"
  version: 2
```

If I run the command: "ip link set dev ens1 down" so the corresponding interface has status "down". If then I run the command "netplan apply" so this interface brings up. How can I change netplan configuration (without committing and lines deleting) in order to have bring down and specified in netplan configuration interfaces not brought up?

Comment: I know, it might sound offtopic, but when you uninstall _netplan_ and use _systemd-networkd_ instead, you might even use _ifupdown_ for unmanaged network devices. _systemd-networkd_ will only manage network devices which have a valid configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

"activation-mode: off" will keep the link state administratively down but configure the addresses. Netplan 0.103 or later is required for this. See https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-yaml/